# Efficient & faster way to merge & group in R

Tags: r, postgresql, data.table, sqldf

I have two datasets and want to do a **inner join** and then **group** but since my data has >100 million rows and inner join is a **cartesian merge** which increases the final dataset further. I want to understand how to do it in an efficient and faster way. My current merge code keeps running for ages.

**Sample datasets** (This example doesn't have cartesian data but my original dataset has)

```
library("data.table")
library("sqldf")
library("purrr")

orders <- data.table(date = as.POSIXct(c('2012-08-28','2012-08-29','2012-09-01', '2012-08-30')),
                     first_name = as.character(c('John','George','Henry', 'Markel')),
                     last_name = as.character(c('Doe','Smith','Smith', 'Markel')),
                     qty = c(10,50,6, 0))

dates <- data.table(date = seq(from = as.POSIXct('2012-08-28'),
                               to = as.POSIXct('2012-09-07'), by = 'day'),
                    week = seq(from = 1, to = 11, by = 1))
```

**Equivalent sqldf code that I have:** This is much slower

```
final_data <- sqldf("select first_name,
       last_name,
       week,
       sum(qty) as total_qty 
from orders a inner join dates b
on a.date = b.date
where a.first_name = a.last_name
group by first_name,
         last_name,
         week
having sum(qty) = 0;")
```

**Equivallent data.table code** (Have to match the sqldf output)

```
final_data_2 <- merge(
    x = orders[ first_name == last_name,]
  , y = dates
  , all = FALSE
  , allow.cartesian = TRUE) %>%
  .[, total_qty := sum(qty), by = .(first_name, last_name, week) ] %>% 
  .[total_qty == 0, .(first_name, last_name, week, total_qty)]
```

**Alternale code by @manoftheshark**

```
orders[dates, on = 'date', allow.cartesian = TRUE][, total_qty := sum(qty), by = .(first_name, last_name, week)][total_qty == 0, .(first_name, last_name, week, total_qty)]
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a cartesian merge?  The sample data does not appear to show this.  It's also unclear how `week` should be handled as it is not part of an aggregate function nor grouped by.

Comment: Yes, my original data is a cartesian merge and this is just an example. The ```week``` is part of select. Hope I am making sense here

Comment: What happens if there is a record such as `2012-09-06, Markel, Markel, 0`?  The `first_name` and `last_name` are grouped and `qty` is summed, but how is `week` handled?  Does it become a distinct record? Or should a single record be returned?

Comment: @manotheshark thanks for pointing this out. I have added week to group by

Comment: When posting question on SO I suggest take out `%>%` and `.` to make it easier to read, and to make it easier to reproduce by reducing extra dependencies. Data processing pipelines can be expressed by chaining `[` operator.

Comment: @jangorecki, actually I had used %>% for piping but i can understand it can be confusing. I have added the code by 'manofthehsark' which will make the code better to understand. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: hi, can quantity be negative?

Comment: @chinsoon12, no it cannot be negative. Just one note is that the sqldf code I mentioned is the output that I needed. I tried the data.table code for one particular instance and it gave me a different result then the sqldf output.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how this will scale to the full data set, but `microbenchmark` was showing a 15-30% improvement with the test data

```
orders[dates, on = 'date', allow.cartesian = TRUE][, total_qty := sum(qty), by = .(first_name, last_name, week)][total_qty == 0, .(first_name, last_name, week, total_qty)]
```

Comment: @manotheshark...just a different question..if the 'on' variable has different names in orders and dates (I mean in order the names is 'dates' and in dates the name is 'date') . Then how can be perform the first step?

Comment: The following syntax should work `orders[dates, on = 'dates==date']` but possibly might need to reverse the order of `on`

Comment: Or use explicit `setkey` and do not provide `on` .

Comment: This method also takes too much of time to run. Thinking of optimising the sqldf code if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Since quantity is non-negative, you can first remove all first_name and last_name with some quantity using an anti-join. Then, lookup the week from the `dates` table. Finally, identify these distinct combinations of first_name, last_name and week:

```
unique(
    orders[!orders[qty>0L], on=.(first_name, last_name)][
        dates, on=.(date), week := week],
    by=c("first_name", "last_name", "week"))
```

Comment: thanks! I also have to give a condition for orders as first_name == last_name. So, I think it can start with orders[(qty == 0L) & (first_name == last_name)][

Comment: First name is the same as last name? Major Major? haha

Comment: haaa...it's just an example

Comment: what does week:= week does? When I am trying it on my actual data it says ```Error in eval(bysub, x, parent.frame()) : object 'week' not found```

Comment: `week := week` add a new week column in `orders[qty==0L]` by looking up from the `dates` table

Comment: actually the prev code is not very correct as first_name, last_name might have non-zero quantity elsewhere. have updated to take care of this scenario. might be slower though